# SOAP security header with UsernameToken and SecurityContextToken - CXF

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

Using CXF and need following security header including UsernameToken (without Password) and SecurityContextToken:

```
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="123">
            <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsc:SecurityContextToken xmlns:wsc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
            <wsc:Identifier>TOKEN</wsc:Identifier>
        </wsc:SecurityContextToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

Tried to use action WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN_NO_PASSWORD and put it in WSS4JOutInterceptor but CXF throws exception "Unknown action defined: UsernameTokenNoPassword".

How can I put these two elements into header?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-604 (which I've just fixed).

Comment: Thanks, Colm. And what is about SecurityContextToken, is it possible to add it via WSHandler?

Comment: Not directly. You could add it via a "CustomToken" action which retrieves a token from a CallbackHandler.

Comment: I can't find CustomToken action in WSSecurityUtil, therefore following exception "Unknown action defined: CustomToken" if I add it as action like props.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.CUSTOM_TOKEN);

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/apache/wss4j/commit/37f48fc1a82d3ba3540a33d0626ac72b336712e2